# Inability to run an SQL statement with a "with" statement in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to run SQL through excel and I have the following SQL query within the data connection:

```
WITH TEST_DB as (select * from TEST_ADM.KPI_SAMPLE_TEST)

SELECT DISTINCT
  BASE.YEAR_MONTH AS YEAR_MONTH
FROM TEST_DB BASE
```

If I try running this with SQL Developer, it will run successfully, no problems but when I try to run it in Excel, I get the message:

> The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened.
>   Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganised, then try the operation again.

Is there some sort of limitation within Excel that prevents me from using WITH statements?
If I remove the statement and select from the table directly, it works but I need to use the WITH data table 6 times in my code and its rather long.

Oh, the database is an oracle database.

Comment: Could it be that the blank line you have between the WITH clause and the SELECT statement is interpreted as a separator (and only the WITH clause is sent to Oracle, without the SELECT)? Perhaps this won't help, but try removing the blank line and send again from Excel for Oracle processing.

Comment: I can confirm that this unfortunately does not work :( I removed the line and got the same error.

Comment: Are you able to run the query (WITHOUT the `with` clause, selecting directly from TEST_ADM.KPI_SAMPLE_TEST) from Excel?

Comment: yes, this works.it appears the ````with```` clause causes a problem. Whilst I could create a subquery every time this table exists, it does make the code a bit messy because the table appears 6 times in the query.